# FORTIFY: vsprintf: prevented 33-byte write into 32-byte buffer

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Good morning, 
I am using a native library on an Android Project, it is just a simple md5hash of the package signature, but
I am facing an issue on 64 bit devices with the JNI function :

```
char *getSignatureMd5(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    char *sign = loadSignature(env, obj);
    MD5_CTX context = {0};
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char *) sign, strlen(sign));
    unsigned char dest[16] = {0};
    MD5Final(dest, &context);
    int i;
    static char destination[32] = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);
    }
    LOGD("MD5 Chacksum : %s", destination);
    return destination;
}
```

I am using it since years so nothing has changed in the code itself, but I guess an NDK or Cmake update causes this :-(
This is the Crash report i get:

```
2020-04-18 08:38:13.038 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '10'
2020-04-18 08:38:13.038 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2020-04-18 08:38:13.038 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5187, tid: 5423, name: APP-AsyncTa  >>> com.pecana.app <<<
2020-04-18 08:38:13.038 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-04-18 08:38:13.040 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'FORTIFY: vsprintf: prevented 33-byte write into 32-byte buffer'
2020-04-18 08:38:13.040 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000152f  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
2020-04-18 08:38:13.040 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000038
2020-04-18 08:38:13.040 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000083  x9  0000007007fb9878  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
2020-04-18 08:38:13.041 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000030  x13 000000005e9aa050  x14 001fb5a729ce1580  x15 000040d9dceb878c
2020-04-18 08:38:13.042 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007007ff02a0  x17 0000007007f2f920  x18 0000000000000000  x19 0000000000001443
2020-04-18 08:38:13.042 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x20 000000000000152f  x21 0000000000000083  x22 000000000000000f  x23 0000006f6a48dcc2
2020-04-18 08:38:13.043 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000004  x25 0000006f5c0f5588  x26 0000006f6b0a04a0  x27 0000000000000001
2020-04-18 08:38:13.043 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000006f5c0f30c0  x29 0000006f5c0f2c00
2020-04-18 08:38:13.044 5621-5621/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000006f5c0f2bc0  lr  0000007007f22d68  pc  0000007007f22d94
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Thank you!

Comment: 16 * 2 (hex digits) + 1 (terminal zero) = 33.

Comment: You are writing 32 bytes to the buffer plus 1 byte for the NULL terminator which you forgot about, so make it `destination[33]` instead of `destination[32]`.

Comment: `I am using it since years`. A buffer overflow all those years.

Comment: `sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);` ?? A very strange construct.

Comment: Hello, still the same error evenif if set destination[33], but is I told it is perfectly working on 32 bit devices. What else can i do ?

Comment: Ok 33 works the first time but once i called the method again it i get "Abort message: 'FORTIFY: vsprintf: prevented 35-byte write into 33-byte buffer'". It seems everytime I call the getsignature it is not cleared but concatenated. Any idea ? @Henri Menke

Comment: Well, you made `destination` static, so it'll only be initialized to `{0}` once. Why do you even need `sprintf` for something as simple as creating a fixed-size hex string?

Comment: @blackapps what would you do instead ?

Comment: @Michael what should I do instead ? I found this on an example to get an md5 of a string and it was working fine and it is working fine on 32 bit devices

Comment: There are various ways you could go about doing that. For example, `static const char DIGITS[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        destination[i*2+0] = DIGITS[(dest[i] >> 4) & 0x0F];
        destination[i*2+1] = DIGITS[dest[i] & 0x0F];
    }`

Comment: Also, you keep saying that it works fine on 32-bit devices. But your 32-bit devices may not have a fortified `vsprintf`. That doesn't mean your code doesn't have the same issue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    static char destination[33] = {0};  // add one more byte for null-terminator
    char* dstptr = destination;         // pointer to first char of the static buffer
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(dstptr, "%02x", dest[i]&0xFF);  // overwrite two chars in buffer
        dstptr += 2;                    // advance pointer
    }
```

This way it will overwrite 32 characters every time, not caring about old content.

Be aware as this seems like some support function for Android code, that if two threads call this simultaneously, the same static buffer is used to produce the result, so you may get damaged answer in both answers (partial answer from one call mixed with part of second). So this is not thread safe.

Plus next call to the function will invalidate the previous version (if you are storing just pointer to the result and you didn't copy it into Java String).

I would probably suggest to return instead newly instanced jstring for direct usage by top Android code (plus it will be maybe thread safe, because all other instances in your code are local variables, only `destination` is static, so if the MD5 functions themselves are thread safe and you get rid of `destination` you will make the whole function thread safe). Not adding the source example of this, because JNI is generally horrible pain for me, killing everything good about C++ and promoting all the bad about it, very prone to do errors and lose types, etc... (my personal toxic bias is - ignore if you are not interested into thrash talk - that it was designed like this on purpose, to avoid too much C/C++ usage together with Java, but then again, it was done so many years back, before C++11, so maybe just the people designing Java were clueless .. actually that makes more sense, considering the whole Java language)

Comment: what would be the return value here ? return dstptr; ? or still return destination; ?

Comment: @Pecana still `destination`, the `dstptr` after the `for` loop points precisely at the null terminator (`destination+32`), i.e. "empty string", while `destination` is pointer to the beginning of the static buffer.

Comment: But I would really suggest to create new `jstring` (check JNI docs how to create jstring instance correctly, it's not trivial) and return that directly (if the result is processed in Java/Kotlin). Unless you work with the result in C++, then static buffer is possible option, although feels fragile to me, with the current way how Android apps are written, anything not thread-safe is potential landmine (as the wrong behaviour will often not show early or on your device, but it will cause weird error reports from customer phones later when project is big and you have no idea where it comes from).

Comment: thanks! I am not returning the value back to android but it is only used inside the library :-)